# Privacy Manifest & Updating MarketingCloudSDK from 7.6.0 to 8.1.2

Tags: marketing-cloud, migration, third-party, manifest, data-protection-and-privacy

To be compliant with Apple's new third party SDK requirements on user data collection and usage privacy guidelines, i'm trying to update to the latest MarketingCloudSDK version 8.1.2.

1. The documentation [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html) says to use SPM to install the newer SDK. Is this mandatory to use SPM? or can we use Cocoapods to update to this version? If Cocoapods is used, are the installation, initialization/Configuration of the SDK steps/code same as if SPM is used? Any particular reason to use SPM?
2. When i update using cocoapods (pod 'MarketingCloudSDK', '~> 8.1.2'), it installs MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk (1.1.2) & MarketingCloudSDK 8.1.2. I see both of them are distributed as xcframeworks and have been signed(which is good). But i do not see the Privacy Manifest files for both, as required by Apple. When will you be providing these?

Comment: Regarding your last question: We are not Salesforce, but Salesforce users, admins, developers just like you. You better ask this for example [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F94S000000kH0HSAU?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC).

Comment: oh! sure, thank you!

Comment: In fact, some Salesforce staff *does* sometimes participate in StackExchange - as this is the case with Prakashini Pattabiraman's answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

#1 -> No it is not mandatory. We have the SDKs on cocoapods as well.
#2 -> The privacy manifest is embedded within the .xcframework for both the SDKs in MarketingCloudSDK 8.1.2 and MarketingCloud-SFMCSdk 1.1.2

Thanks
Prakashini

Comment: I see them. Thank you. But i dont see any privacy tracking or privacy tracking domains in those privacy manifest files of yours? We are tracking user's account (using SFMCSdk.identity.setProfileId) and device info right? shouldn't you be setting these in the SDK's manifest file?

Comment: Hi, We do not track users account in the SDK. We have evaluated on what should be part of the manifest with our legal team and based on that we have added our privacy manifests. Thanks, Prakashini